# custom express in angular-cli devserver

Tags: angular, angular-cli

current angualr version: @17.*

I want to use a customized express as devserver, in which I can customize some special configurations, such as middleware, routing, etc.

In fact, I am now trying to make a front-end and back-end isomorphic project, which has been initially set up, using angular + nestjs.

I don't want to start two servers during the development process, so I currently use the cruder method of ng build --watch + webpack hmr to develop.

I don't want to stop there and try to use express instead of ng's devserver.

I'm not familiar with the code of devserver. I guess there is a method similar to Adapter or Factory to load express, but after looking at the source code of cli, it seems that it is coupled. I can't extract the code of the server creation part separately. , I also need to rewrite the entire HMR logic.

Based on the current situation, I want to try to enable ng's devserver to load an external express example first, and then explore the rest. (Perhaps there is already a mature solution that I don’t know about?)

what should I do?